# TensorFlow: slow performance when getting gradients at inputs

Tags: tensorflow

I'm building a simple multilayer perceptron with TensorFlow, and I also need to obtain the gradients (or error signal) of the loss at the neural network's inputs.

Here's my code, which works:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(self.network, self.y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=nn_learning_rate).minimize(cost)
...
for i in range(epochs):
    ....
    for batch in batches:
        ...
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        grads_wrt_input = sess.run(tf.gradients(cost, self.x), feed_dict=feed_dict)[0]
```

(edited to include training loop)

Without the last line (`grads_wrt_input...`), this runs really fast on a CUDA machine. However, `tf.gradients()` reduces performance greatly by tenfold or more.

I recall that the error signals at the nodes are computed as intermediate values in the backpropagation algorithm, and I have successfully done this using the Java library DeepLearning4j. I was also under the impression that this would be a slight modification to the computation graph already built by `optimizer`.

How can this be made faster, or is there any other way to compute the gradients of the loss w.r.t. the inputs?

Comment: Are you literally calling `tf.gradients()` in the training loop? If so I suspect the overhead is from building the backprop graph each time you call it?

Comment: I've included the training loop code for clarity; yes I'm calling `tf.gradients()` in the training loop.

The program slows down progressively. What should I do to prevent this building overhead?

Comment: Call tf.gradients outside of the loop to construct the computation graph for gradients once. Also you can reuse gradient graph made for your optimizer by using compute_gradients

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `tf.gradients()` function builds a new backpropagation graph each time it is called, so the reason for the slowdown is that TensorFlow has to parse a new graph on each iteration of the loop. (This can be surprisingly expensive: the current version of TensorFlow is optimized for executing the *same* graph a large number of times.)

Fortunately the solution is easy: just compute the gradients once, outside the loop. You can restructure your code as follows:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(self.network, self.y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=nn_learning_rate).minimize(cost)
grads_wrt_input_tensor = tf.gradients(cost, self.x)[0]
# ...
for i in range(epochs):
    # ...
    for batch in batches:
        # ...
        _, grads_wrt_input = sess.run([optimizer, grads_wrt_input_tensor],
                                      feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Note that, for performance, I also combined the two `sess.run()` calls. This ensures that the forward propagation, and much of the backpropagation, will be reused.

---

As an aside, one tip to find performance bugs like this is to call [`tf.get_default_graph().finalize()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.finalize) before starting your training loop. This will raise an exception if you inadvertantly add any nodes to the graph, which makes it easier to trace the cause of these bugs.

Comment: That worked, thank you! My program is now fast.

BTW, I think `grads_wrt_input` in the list in the `sess.run()` call should be `grads_wrt_input_tensor`.