# TensorFlow: Each iteration in training for-loop slower

Tags: python, for-loop, tensorflow

I'm training a standard, simple multilayer perceptron ANN with three hidden layers in TensorFlow. I added a text progress bar so I could watch the progress of iterating through the epochs. What I'm finding is that the processing time per iteration increases after the first few epochs. Here's an example screenshot showing the increase with each iteration:

[image: Execution time per iteration increases with # of iterations]

In this case, the first few iterations took roughly 1.05s/it and by 100% it was taking 4.01s/it.

The relevant code is listed here:

```
# ------------------------- Build the TensorFlow Graph -------------------------

with tf.Graph().as_default():

    (a bunch of statements for specifying the graph)

# --------------------------------- Training ----------------------------------

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    print "Start Training"

    pbar = tqdm(total = training_epochs)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.0
    batch_iter = 0

    while batch_iter < batch_size:
        train_features = []
        train_labels = []
        batch_segments = random.sample(train_segments, 20)
        for segment in batch_segments:
            train_features.append(segment[0])
            train_labels.append(segment[1])
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: train_features, y_: train_labels})
        line_out = "," + str(batch_iter) + "\n"
        train_outfile.write(line_out)
        line_out = ",," + str(sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(weights['h1']), feed_dict={x: train_features, y_: train_labels}))
        line_out += "," + str(sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(weights['h2']), feed_dict={x: train_features, y_: train_labels}))
        line_out += "," + str(sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(weights['h3']), feed_dict={x: train_features, y_: train_labels})) + "\n"
        train_outfile.write(line_out)
        avg_cost += sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: train_features, y_: train_labels})/batch_size

        batch_iter += 1

    pbar.update(1)  # Increment the progress bar by one

train_outfile.close()
print "Completed training"
```

In searching stackoverflow, I found [Processing time gets longer and longer after each iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230559/processing-time-gets-longer-and-longer-after-each-iteration-tensorflow) where someone else was also having problems with each iteration taking longer than the last. However, I believe mine may be different since they were clearly adding ops to the graph using statements like so:

```
distorted_image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image_tensor)
```

While I'm new to TensorFlow, I don't believe that I'm making the same mistake because the only stuff in my loop are sess.run() calls.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Adding in the body of the loop with session.run call forces serialization/copying of the entire graph, so this kind of loop has quadratic complexity. You can do `self.tf.get_default_graph().finalize()` to make you don't have accidental modifications of graph like this

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, thanks for pointing me to the finalize() function. I didn't know about that. I was able to find a few other places where I was accidently adding ops to the graph.

Comment: @etarion, I explicitly made reference to the other thread (it was the hyperlink for "this post") and felt mine was different. I'll edit my question to make this clear.

Comment: @etarion, after a second look I think you are correct. I got thrown off because I thought that putting an op within a sess.run() wouldn't result in a modification to the graph.

While I'm okay with this question being marked as a duplicate, I think the answers from YaroslavBulatov and Vincent are contributions and they should not be discarded.

Comment: @DojoGojira, closing as duplicate doesn't discard answers, it just prevents new answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245481/tensorflow-slow-performance-when-getting-gradients-at-inputs is also another case of this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The three places where you have:

```
sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(weights['h1']), ...)
```

each append a new `tf.reduce_mean()` node to the graph **at each iteration of the while loop**, which adds overhead. Try to create them outside of the while loop:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  ...
  m1 = tf.reduce_mean(weights['h1'])

while batch_iter < batch_size:
  ...
  line_out = ",," + str(sess.run(m1, feed_dict={x: train_features, y_: train_labels}))
```

Comment: What Yaroslav says above is also correct in this instance.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know about the finalize() function. Your answer was very helpful so I gave you the checkmark, but I did end up using his answer to find a few other places where I accidently added ops to the graph. Thanks for your very clear answer.