# Tensorflow performance degrades over time

Tags: performance, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have some tensorflow code (nothing complicated), and am measuring the time per minibatch. For some reason, the time per minibatch gets longer and longer from batch to batch. It ends up taking around 6 times as long for each batch than it does for the first batch.

I seem to be experiencing the exact same thing as this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472787/tensorflow-l2-loss-training-time-per-iteration-increases-over-time).

The following results in the slowdown

```
self._loss =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf.to_int64(self._label_placeholder)))
for W, b in layers:
    self._loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(W) * rho
```

However, if I use:

```
self._loss =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf.to_int64(self._label_placeholder)))
# for W, b in layers:
#     self._loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(W) * rho
```

The time per minibatch does not increase over time. I also tried manually computing the Frobenius of my matrices and got the same slowdown.

What can I do to incorporate regularization without getting a massive slowdown?

Comment: It's hard to give a good answer without seeing a complete example, but my usual approach is to start by investigating with a profiler. Here are some details on how to do that if you're using the GPU: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-225754659

Comment: Just to reiterate, removing the calls to tf.nn.l2_loss fixes the issue.

Comment: Are you using the 0.10rc0 version of TensorFlow by any change? It had some a performance regression in the implementation of `tf.nn.l2_loss()` and some other reduction ops, which is fixed in the official 0.10 release (and the nightly versions).

Comment: Installed from this link, so unless it doesn't include the rc in the URL then no. https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

Comment: Furthermore, I actually got the same slowdown between batches when I manually computed the L2 loss with tf.square and tf.reduce_sum

Comment: @mrry The person who asked the question originally (around a year ago) replied to me saying that he had the problem in a VM, but didn't experience it running on a physical machine. I have the problem on an AWS instance, but can't easily test it on a physical machine.

Comment: Are you sure your graph is finished and you're not adding ops to the graph every time you call session.run? That's usually the cause of per-batch slowdowns.

Comment: Yes I was quite sure. This was research code two years ago and worked fine after a few more TF versions.