# Poor performance when using TensorFlow input functions in a loop

Tags: performance, opencv, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am currently training a set of around 10,000 images with ten epochs. My question is regarding the following code:

```
            file_contents = cv2.imread(shuffle_image_list[i],3)
            resized_image = cv2.resize(file_contents, (72,72), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA) 
            data = np.array(resized_image)
            flattened = data.flatten() 

            #image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([resized_image, shuffle_label_list[i]], batch_size=batch_size) # does train.batch take individual images or final tensors
            #if(i>batch_size):
                #print(label_batch.eval())
            print(str(i))
            imageArr.append(flattened)
            labelArr.append(int(shuffle_label_list[i]))
            if i % 100 == 0:
                print("....... " + str(i))
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: imageArr, y: labelArr})
                epoch_loss += c
                imageArr = []
                labelArr = []
```

Here, I am feeding images in mini-batches of 100 to the neural network. The code is initially getting a string, file_contents. Then that string is being decoded into a jpg. However, when I use TensorFlow's functions, such as tf.decode_jpeg and tf.reshape(), etc., there is a difference in speed. When using TensorFlow's functions to accomplish the same task of decoding images, it starts out fast in the training process, and then becomes incredibly slow after the first epoch.

To put this in perspective, using OpenCV, I could train this entire model with 10 epochs in around 1hr and 30 minutes. However, using TensorFlow's functions, it took over 12 hours to get past the first epoch and midway through the second, I stopped the training process after I saw the progress it was making.

I am not sure if this as anything to do with the concept of network slowdown, as seen [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-neural-network-learning-slow-down-as-the-error-gets-lower-Does-this-need-to-be-the-case). I am simply replacing OpenCV functions with TensorFlow functions to decode an image and read a file. Why is there such as dramatic speed difference between OpenCV and TensorFlow? Why exactly does TensorFlow's functions slow down as the code progresses? Will this have any effect on the accuracy of model?

Note: The only functions I changed were at the top. I didn't use tf.train.batch in either versions. The only thing that was changed was the lines of code from file_contents to data.flatten(), to corresponding tensorflow functions.

Comment: I suspect you're calling `tf.train.batch()` in each iteration of some outer `for` loop, and so the TensorFlow graph is growing with each iteration. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36250569/3574081) for a discussion of how to fix this.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I didn't use tf.train.batch, I'll update the question

Comment: Can you show what the code with "the corresponding TensorFlow functions" looks like? I suspect that whatever you called (e.g. `tf.decode_jpeg()`), if you call it in the loop, it will have the same underlying issue as the problem in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36250569/3574081).

Comment: Yes, tf.decode_jpeg and tf.readfile. Why would it have the same underlying issues as that problem?

Comment: Calling these functions adds nodes to your graph. Every time you add one or more nodes to the graph and call `sess.run()`, TensorFlow does work that's linear in the current size of the graph. If you have a loop that adds a constant number of nodes in each iteration, you'll unfortunately end up doing work that's quadratic in the number of iterations, which explains why your program slows down. Call `tf.decode_jpeg()` and `tf.read_file()` outside the loop and use feeding/placeholders to pass in a new filename each time.