# Tensorflow loading data randomly slows down during training

Tags: tensorflow

I have loaded all the training data in the memory, which only consumes 7% of the total memory. And the following framework is used to train the model:

```
# build graph
......
# data producer
class DataProducer(object):
  # a single feature has multiple labels and is needed to be trained separately for each label
  # in order to not copy the features multiple times, I use the self.ft_idxs to index the relationships between features and labels
  def yield_trn_batch(self, batch_size):
    for i in xrange(0, self.num_data, batch_size):
      fts = self.fts[self.ft_idxs[self.shuffled_idxs[i: i+batch_size]]
      labels = self.labels[self.shuffled_idxs[i: i+batch_size]]
      yield fts, labels

# training
for feature, label in data.yield_trn_batch(batch_size):
  sess.run(model.train_op, feed_dict={model.feature: feature, model.label: label})
```

However, the training process randomly slows down when the dimensionality of the feature is high.
The diagnoses are as following:

1. The graph is predefined and is not the case in [tensorflow slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245481/tensorflow-slow-performance-when-getting-gradients-at-inputs).
2. The actual running time for sess.run() is stable and the following is the timeline of a training batch, which seems normal. [image: timeline of a training batch]
3. The slow part happened in data.yield_trn_batch(). At the begining, it took 0.01s to load one minibatch, but after several epoches it became unstable and sometimes took over 1s to load a minibatch. However, when I commented the sess.run() and purely run the data.yield_trn_batch(), it was fast as normal. I don't use the queue so it might not be the situation in [dequeue many operation very slow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3009).

I guess the graph running process have affected the data loading but don't know why and how to solve this (maybe using another thread to load data?). Can anybody fix the problem?

Comment: I think we'll need more details to solve this problem. Is your Python process consuming a lot of memory? Can you share the code of `data.yield_trn_batch(batch_size)`? If you feed the same batch over and over again does it still slow down?

Comment: I updated the code and memory usage. And the speed doesn't seem to grow after several epochs when I feed the same batch. Is there any problems of the data yield code?

Comment: My guess is that the array slice you're yielding is an awkward size for the memory allocator used by Python, and each batch is increasing the size of the heap (not a memory leak, per se, but freed memory won't be reused as you'd hope). Can you try using `tcmalloc` as described in [this doc](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/3883/how-to-debug-a-memory-leak-in-tensorflow/13427/use-the-tcmalloc-allocator#t=20170304002146036458)?

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our conversation in the comments, it appears that the slow down is due to memory pressure caused by allocating a large number of NumPy arrays. Although the NumPy arrays are properly garbage collected properly when they are no longer used, the default `malloc()` implementation will not reuse them, and gradually increase the size of the heap (and the virtual size of the process), by calling the `brk()` system call.

One workaround is to switch the allocator library, which can fix address space leaks: use the `tcmalloc` allocator instead of the default `malloc()` for your TensorFlow process. The allocation policy in `tcmalloc` is better suited to allocating and recycling buffers of the same size repeatedly, and it will not need to increase the size of the head over time, which should lead to better performance.