# How to realize a algorithm like Momentum in TensorFlow? Why my algorithm so slow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I want to realize the Momentum algorithm using TensorFlow. However my algorithm is so slow on the mnist. And every iteration is slower than last. I have a Nvidia TitanX pascal, it's really fast when training the demo in tensorflow offical website. So, it's not the problem of the GPU.

Here is my code (momentum and modified momentum):

```
def momentum(loss, t, parameter_list):
opt = GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-3)
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss, parameter_list)
capped_grads_and_vars = []
for i in range(len(grads_and_vars)):
    gradient = grads_and_vars[i][0]
    variable = grads_and_vars[i][1]
    if t != 0:
        momentum = gradient + mu * last_momentum0[i]
        capped_grads_and_vars.append((momentum, variable))
    else:
        momentum = gradient
        capped_grads_and_vars.append((momentum, variable))
if t != 0:
    for i in range(len(grads_and_vars)):
        last_momentum0[i] = capped_grads_and_vars[i][0]
else:
    for i in range(len(grads_and_vars)):
        last_momentum0.append(capped_grads_and_vars[i][0])
return opt.apply_gradients(capped_grads_and_vars)
```

[the time of the session.run(train_step)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSJNL.png)

Comment: How does your training loop look like?

Comment: Usually the problem when "it gets slower each iteration" is the problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230559/processing-time-gets-longer-and-longer-after-each-iteration-tensorflow but without more information there's no way to be sure.